# [Flutter]Display notification when app is terminated and an FCM Data Message is received

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-local-notification

How do I display a notification when an fcm data message is received in my flutter app when my app is not running or completely terminated?

Because, right now, the notifications work when the app is running in the foreground or just minimized. But, the moment the application is killed, notifications from fcm messages are no longer displayed.

Here is my current fcm setup

```
_handleFCMMessage(RemoteMessage message, [bool onBackgroundIsolate = false]) {
  Map<String, dynamic> data = message.data;
  String type = data["type"];
  switch (type) {
    case "post_ready":
      //Display notification here
      //Notification data omitted for code brevity
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show();// this is not working despite all I've tried. It only works when the fcm message was received in the foreground
      break;
    default:
      //Do nothing
      break;
  }
}
_firebaseMessagingForegroundHandler() {
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(
    (message) => _handleFCMMessage(message, false),
  );
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  _handleFCMMessage(message, true);
}

main() async {
  ...
  _firebaseMessagingForegroundHandler();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
 ...
}
```

Meanwhile I already have flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin setup at the app level in my main.dart file.

From the fcm docs, I was told fcm messages received in the background will be spawed in its own isolate. Could that be the reason my existing flutterLocalNotifications.show method is not working?

How do I solve this and reuse my existing flutterlocalNotifications plugin instead of creating a new one?